# How to remove time format from dropdownlist ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, crystal-reports-2010

I have a dropdownlist where populated with database as date value. In the database the type data is 'date' not with time, but dropdownlist is loaded with time format

```
 Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT tahun_lulus_kuliah from alumni", conn)
    Dim ds = New DataSet
    ds.Clear()
    da.Fill(ds, "alumni")
    DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables("alumni")
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = ("tahun_lulus_kuliah")
    DropDownList1.DataBind()
```

this is screenshoot of dropdownlist, and it's possible change format dropdownlist become "yyyy/mm/dd" without time format?

[image]

Thank You very Much
Hope Your Answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `DropDownList.DataTextFormatString` to `"{0:yyyy/mm/dd}"`.

```
<asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList1"
    ...
    DataTextFormatString="{0:yyyy/mm/dd}"/>
```

Comment: I'd that but the output result is nothing, the dropdownlist still give same format, no change,
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

something like this. if you want to do it in the back end. Not a VB boy so I haven't confirmed it.

```
Binding dateBinding = new Binding("tahun_lulus_kuliah", ds.Tables("alumni"), "")

dateBinding.FormattingEnabled = True
dateBinding.FormatString = "yyyy/mm/dd"
DropDownList.DataBindings.Add(dateBinding)
```

Comment: Hello Mr. Tony,
Thank Your very much sir,
but can you give me c# code, it's ok for me,

Comment: I've fixed the tag on your question as well, was only the vb dim that needed changing. Still haven't proved it. More info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480734.aspx